# Datatables fetch next 10 items when click next from ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, pagination, datatables

i am creating a table with pagination using datatables. i have big data called using ajax. The ajax call returning 10 data at once. when first call, it takes first 10 data from ajax call. then when click next page it will take another 10 data. As i know, datatables collect all data and do it own pagination. How can i solve my problem. Example if ajax returning 100 data from backend, how will the datatables know 10 pages it need to generate. and the data will only call when we click next.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

1. Retrieve 100 data records from your back end at once, calculate the number of pages needed in javascript and display 10 first records. When the next page button is clicked, your display the next 10 records, and so on.
2. Retrieve the first 10 data records from your back end along with the offset of the last record. Display your records to users. When the next page button is clicked, call another ajax to retrieve the next 10 data records (that should be easy since you got the offset of the last record), and display them again.

This is the general idea on how to solve your problem. Hope it helps!

Comment: i'm doing the second option. because the backend can took 10 data per call. but how the datatables pagination knows how many page. example i have 100 records, then because ajax call send 10 result first, the table only show one page and disabled the next page since it assume 1 page only

Comment: you can use offset to return 10 records at a time..but you also need to return the number of total records from the backend. something like count(*) .. based on this datatables will know the total number of records and will display pagination accordingly.